# Ionic Local Notifications icon not shown when app is in background

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, localnotification, ionic-native

I need to customize the icon for local notifications, after reading few questions and answers:

[How to change ionic 2 local push notification icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821954/how-to-change-ionic-2-local-push-notification-icon)

[Ionic 2 : Local notification icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117124/ionic-2-local-notification-icon)

I managed to make it work in the foreground, the icon is shown correctly.

**The problem comes when the application is in background and recieves the notification**, the notification is shown but the icon not, **It shows a white square**.

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
      title: data.title,
      text: data.message,
      data: data,
      icon: 'ic_notification',
      smallIcon: 'ic_notification_small'
    });
```

I have two images in res/drawable both with transparent background, the big one is 192x192px and the small one is 24x24px, I don`t know what is smallIcon used for.